# Rails: get records through many other records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have rails app with 3 tables:

```
#jobs
  has_many :favorite_industries
```

```
#industries
  has_many :favorite_industries
```

```
#favorite_industry
  belongs_to :industry
  belongs_to :job
```

How can I get jobs in multiple industries like `industry_ids(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`

Answer (score 0):

the has many associations should be pluralized:

```rb
  has_many :favorite_industries
```

then the query you're looking for would be

```rb
Job.joins(:favorite_industries).where(industry_id: [1,2,3,4,5,6])
```